# How to get attributes from array of objects to create different model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have a Rails server running on the background used to capture API requests. Inside Rails, I have 2 associated models: `schedule` and `worker`. `schedule has_many workers` and `worker belongs_to schedule`

I am making a POST request from React (fetch method), this is what it looks like on React:

```
  return fetch(`api/schedules`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      date: date,
      message: message,
      user_id: 1,
      worker_info: {name: workerName, phone: phone}
    })
```

On Rails schedules_controller:

```
  def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
    @worker = @schedule.workers.new(worker_params)
    @worker.save
    if @schedule.save
      render json: @schedule
    else
      render json: @schedule, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  ...

  def schedule_params
    params.require(:schedule).permit(:date, :message, :user_id)
  end

  def worker_params
    params.require(:worker_info).permit(:name, :phone)
  end
```

**Note, the codes above works fine**

I want to send to `api/schedules` several parameters: `date, message, user_id`, and some worker info (`name, phone`).

Schedule itself has attributes `date, message,` and `user_id`. Worker has attributes `name` and `phone`. My plan is to make only ***one*** request to Rails, stub some worker info, and let Rails create worker object inside Schedule. Again, I can do that with code above.

My question is, the complexity increases when I try to send, instead of a single object `worker_info`, an array of `worker_infos`.

```
worker_info: [{name: workerName, phone: phone}]
```

(In the future, I want to send a variable amount of workers, that's why I added the array. Right now, I just need to make it work with just one)

```
worker_info: [{name: 'Test Worker 1', phone: '12345'}, {name: 'Test Worker 2', phone: '54321'}, ...]
```

I cannot figure out how to extract worker information to make worker object if I add the array `[]`. Here is the rails server error:

```
Started POST "/api/schedules" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-25 17:19:32 -0700
Processing by SchedulesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"date"=>"2017-05-27T02:00:00.000Z", "message"=>"Mireya Hiya~!!", "user_id"=>1, "worker_info"=>[{"name"=>"Mireya How
e", "phone"=>"1234567890"}], "schedule"=>{"date"=>"2017-05-27T02:00:00.000Z", "user_id"=>1, "message"=>"Hello test!!"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for #<Array:0x007f8381fd2530>):

app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:59:in `worker_params'
app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:20:in `create'
```

*I am avoiding Rails' `accept_nested_attributes_for`method because the way my other code is structured, it won't work and has been causing much grief.*

How can I extract the information inside `worker_info: [{name: workerName, phone: phone}]` and create new Worker object with that?

Comment: You should probably add your `worker_params` method to your question since that is clearly where the error is occurring.

Comment: Sorry! I just realized that too. Added it on the Rails code block^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho, man.

First of all, good on 'ya for avoiding `accept_nested_attributes_for`. What a cluster you-know-what.

So, the whole point of `strong parameters` is to be able to whitelist stuff when doing mass assignment. This doesn't really seem like a mass assignment situation, so I would abandon ship on the whole approach.

Instead, I would go bare knuckles codez. You know, something like:

```
app/services/api/schedules/workers_service.rb

class Api::Schedules::WorkersService

  class < self

    def call(params={})
      ...
      # do a bunch of clever stuff
      ...
    end

  end
end
```

And then in `SchedulesController`, do something like:

```
def create
  @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
  if @schedule.save
    Api::Schedules::WorkersService.call(
      schedule_id: @schedule.id,
      worker_info: params[:worker_info]
    )
    render json: @schedule
  else
    render json: @schedule, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

You probably want to wrap some of that junk in a transaction in case things go South.

Comment: Yo! Thanks - I am still having trouble figuring out how to save the Object. I think I got the general idea. The service ought to convert the array of object into a plain object - right? I have not much experience with this, would you mind elaborating? I did something like `def call(params={}); puts params...` and it shows `:worker_info=>[<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Mr. Cassandre Sanford", "phone"=>"(818)-943-9150"} permitted: false>]}`. How do I create a worker object from that, and what should go to into `call` method?

Comment: It's probably a longer conversation, we can [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/145238/how-to-get-attributes-from-array-of-objects-to-create-different-model-in-rails?tab=general) if you like

Comment: Hey jvillian, sure! I am available now.